# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar los permisos de un archivo en C++?

Tags: c++

Quiero cambiar los permisos de un archivo.

He intentado con la función `permissions("hello_m.txt",perms::owner_all | perms::group_all, perm_options::add);`, pero no puedo, ya que las propiedades de seguridad del archivo me lo impide.

Esto es lo que obtengo al ejecutar:

> *terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
> what():  filesystem error: cannot set permissions: Permission denied [hello_m.txt]*

Comment: Si el programa no cuenta con los privilegios para poder modificar el archivo o establecer sus permisos tiene sentido que obtengas errores. Prueba ejecutandolo como administrador o root.